# Best way to mask dynamic data (timestamps) using ScalaTest

Tags: regex, scala, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest for my unit testing.  I have a test result (JSON) that might look like below.  The actual result is huge and complex.  This is an example.

```
[{"name":"George", "when":143828333, ...}, {"name":"Fred", "when":14857777, ... }]
```

The 'when' field values are dynamic and will change from test-to-test (i.e. current timestamp), so I can't test against these.  I could use some regex to mask these out, basically replacing them with some inert token.

Does ScalaTest have an more elegant way of handling dynamic bits of data like this?

Comment: In a typical setup you would mock the module that generates these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done many times in the past in this situation is exactly what you propose: use a regex to replace the dates with a constant so your comparisons will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom Equality for the types you're comparing. Your custom Equality can ignore the dynamic fields for the equality comparison. Info on Equality is here:

http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.0/index.html#org.scalactic.Equality

All you need to do is define the areEqual method and then make it implicit. So Equality[JsonType] or Equality[String], whatever the type is. This will then be picked up by the === operator and the equal matcher in your assertions.